# javascript воспроизведение Audio

Tags: javascript, аудио, raspberry-pi

Собираю плейлист для Audio.

```
var songs = ['http://192.168.254.224:8087/voice/1.wav',
'http://192.168.254.224:8087/voice/2.wav',
'http://192.168.254.224:8087/voice/3.wav',
'http://192.168.254.224:8087/voice/4.wav',
'http://192.168.254.224:8087/voice/5.wav',
]
  var audio = new Audio()
  audio.song = 0
  audio.src = songs[audio.song]
  audio.onended = function (e) {
    if (this.song === songs.length - 1) {
      return
    } else {
      this.song++
    }
    this.src = songs[this.song]
    this.play()
  }
  audio.play()
```

Проблема в том что первый трек (он короткий примерно 2 секунды), то не воспроизводится вовсе, то воспроизводится конец трека.
Подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему.

Выяснилось что данная проблема происходит только на устройстве raspbery Pi3 с ОС raspbian

> audio.addEventListener('loadeddata', function () {
>       loaded = true
>       play(audio, songs)   },

Аудио 100% прогружается., а само воспроизведение начинается с задержкой

Comment: Евгений, данный девайс, все же слабый...  Может стоит какой-нить прелодер использовать

Comment: Добавил в описание темы

Comment: А если формат `mp3`, проблема такая же? попробуй изменить формат треков

Comment: На бэкенде много чего менять придётся

Comment: А что насчет прелоадинга всех звуков, а только потом их воспроизведение ? т.е. для каждого song использовать свой объект Audio с `preload = "auto"`. тогда после окончания первой песни надо будет просто подменить объект Audio нужной песни

Comment: Думаю что буду «прогревать» raspberry пустым треком, длиной в первый трек, там порядка 3 секунд

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что на этом устройстве требуется чуть по-больше промежуток времени между  audio.src = "такой-то" и audio.play(); Попробуйте ещё audio.play(), который в конце кода поместить во внутрь функции audio.onloadeddata=function(){audio.play()} или создать для audio.play() задержку во времени.